# Screw specification for ceiling electric box

Tags: electrical

Is there a standard size screw for electric boxes in ceilings?   Box is 25 years old and I am installing a new fan.  [image]

UPDATE: a fan was removed from these boxes, however, the contractor did not keep the screws

Comment: Answer will vary with what part of the world you are in (this is a global website) and you or your painter really should have taped off those wires before painting.

Comment: ...And also caulked the box to the drywall. That's a huge air leak into/out of your attic.

Comment: Can you find the markings on the box?  If it's a fan rated box, it'll say so...

Answer (score 11):

Device (switch) boxes are 6-32. Junction boxes like that one are 8-32. Ground screws are 10-32.

Also, you could buy a ceiling hugger style fan instead of a stem mounted one, and fasten it directly to the ceiling with toggle bolts or similar fasteners, instead of just the box, since that box is most likely not rated for a fan.

Good luck and stay safe!

Comment: Toggle bolts into drywall would almost certainly be worse than a non ceiling-fan rated box. I would most definitely not suggest that as an alternative. If you are unsure about the safety of the box the box should be replaced with a rated box.

Answer (score 9):

First, this has to be a properly installed **ceiling fan box** - you can't put a fan on a lamp box because the dynamic forces of the vibration will tear it out of the ceiling.

On *normal* electrical boxes, screws are usually 6-32... this being a bit light for a fan, also expect 8-32 or 10-32.   Ground screws are 10-32. It's not a coincidence that they are -32, given the thickness of standard metal junction boxes, that is the minimum number of threads to properly engage.  Never use sheetmetal screws.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much everywhere code in the USA states that you need a ceiling fan rated box.  The box is stronger and comes with all mounting hardware in multiple types from joist to between joist options. I personally used this product for all my interior and deck fan mounts and I have 60 inch fans on the porch deck.  https://www.lowes.com/pd/Raco-1-Gang-Gray-Steel-Interior-New-Work-Standard-Ceiling-Fan-Electrical-Box/1099543

Comment: This does not answer the question. Since the OP is "installing a new fan" the box is quite possibly already a ceiling fan box (i think I see a big rivet on the back) and in any case, the question is about screw sizes, not type of box. It might be a comment, it's certainly not an answer to this question.

Comment: The OP says the box is 25 years old. That "rivet" might be the hickey fastening the box to the spreader bar. However, he still didn't answer the OPs question.