# screws for ceiling fan box

Tags: ceiling-fan, screws

I am trying to replace  ceiling fan and unfortunately I didn't save the two screws to attach the fan bracket to the junction box. I thought it comes with the fan. So, what screws should I buy now. In the picture you can see two holes circled in red color.
Thanks,
PRT
[image]

Comment: They usually _do_ come with the fan. Are you sure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @isherwood commented, [this previous question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/122149/screw-specification-for-ceiling-electric-box) has much info on this.

As noted there, it is important to use a special fan-rated box to mount a (heavy & vibrating) fan. That will use thicker machine screws. Hopefully, that is what you already have in place. I found this ceiling fan box with rotating bolt mounts labeled 10-32 for fan use and 8-32 for other fixture use. Thus, you should need 10-32 machine screws (#10 32tpi).

[image]